# WAPT Supported Requests

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, wapt

What are the supported protocols/ request types in WAPT for load testing?
Requests like; FTP, SMTP, JMS, JDBC, LDAP, SOAP and TCP are supported in WAPT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only http(s). Components requiring other protocols can be tested through web interfaces.